# How to understand this function to accept numbers as input and reverse them?

Tags: c#

How can I better understand this code? The point of this function is to have user input numbers and the program returns the numbers reversed.

I'm just curious to know how it works, what exactly in the reverse function is doing the reversing? I tried doing the math but I keep hitting a roadblock.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 0, result = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a Number: ");
        n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        result = reverse(n);
        Console.WriteLine("The Reverse Number Is : " + result);
        Console.ReadKey();        
    }

    public static int reverse(int n)
    {
        int temp = 0, rev = 0;

        while( n != 0)
        {
            temp = n % 10;
            rev = (rev * 10) + temp;
            n = n / 10;
        }

        return rev;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code?

Comment: Be more specific. What part do you not understand?

Comment: You should use the debugger and look at the variables involved in the reverse function. Looking at how they change step by step should be of great help to understand how that function works. As always, being a programmer means to know and use the tools of the trade. And the debugger is the most important one

Comment: Take a pencil and paper. Pick a number e.g. 123. Now work though the reverse function line by line and keep track of temp, rev, and n. I find this approach helps clarify exactly what is going on.

Comment: lets say the number is 293. The remainder of 293 when divided by 10 is 3 right? so temp = 3. what are we multiplying by 10 in the line rev = (rev*10) +  temp and how does this return the reverse of 293 when n is divided by 10 in the final step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what's happening in the reverse function is the following:

This line divides `n` by ten and takes the remainder, effectively taking the last digit of the number.

`temp = n % 10;`

---

This line shifts all digits in the reversed number one to the left and adds the `temp` digit to the right of it.

`rev = (rev * 10) + temp;`

---

This line removes the final digit from the original number. In combination with the while loop, this means that the loop will go on until every digit has been removed from `n`.

`n = n / 10;`

---

Perhaps it is clearer to go through an example:

Let's start with `n = 12345`. We take the last digit with `temp = n % 10;`, which is 5. Next we go through `rev = (rev * 10) + temp;`. `rev` starts at 0. 0 * 10 = 0, + 5 = 5. So now `rev = 5`. We remove the final digit from `n` with `n = n / 10;`. So now `n = 1234` and `rev = 5`.

In the next iteration, we take the final digit of `n`, 4. `rev` currently is 5. 5 * 10 = 50, + 4 = 54. After removing the final digit, `n = 123` and `rev = 54`.

In the next iteration, we take the final digit of `n`, 3. `rev` currently is 54. 54 * 10 = 540, + 3 = 543. After removing the final digit, `n = 12` and `rev = 543`.

In the next iteration, we take the final digit of `n`, 2. `rev` currently is 543. 543 * 10 = 5430, + 2 = 5432. After removing the final digit, `n = 1` and `rev = 5432`.

In the next iteration, we take the final (and only) digit of `n`, 1. `rev` currently is 5432. 5432 * 10 = 54320, + 1 = 54321. After removing the final digit, `n = 0` and `rev = 54321`.

`while( n != 0)` is now false, so there is no next iteration. The function ends with `n = 0` and `rev = 54321` and it returns the value of `rev`, which is 54321, which is the reverse of 12345.

Answer (score 0):

The code `n % 10` returns the residual of `n/10`. So in first iteration you get the first digit from right and put it in **temp**. Then using `n=n/10` you omit the first digit and ready to get the second digit using `n % 10` again. For adding the second digit to the the right of first digit, we can push the first one to the left using `rev = (rev * 10)` and add the second digit to the right of **rev** using `rev = (rev * 10) +temp` and so on.

Comment: By the way, if an answer (or answers) is useful enough for a thank you, consider up-voting it. In addition, if one of the answers fully answers you question, you should accept it.